# PermissionStatus.restricted - image gallery FLUTTER

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I'm debugging my Android device and trying to pick an image with `image_picker` through `ImageSource.gallery`.

The device is asking permission for ALL storage (I'm using `permission_handler`).

The problem is when I try to check permission status for `manageExternalStorage` which comes up always as `Restricted`.

Is there a way to check permission for `Storage`?

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67151525/15023395

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by changing the permission from `manageExternalStorage` which is restricted to `storage`.